# Restaurant sql reserervations with base schedule availability and exceptions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

Im working on a project where users can place reservations with restaurants, but only on the dates that the restaurant allows. The restaurant can also set how many seats are available at a certain time.

So a restaurant can supply a schedule which is formatted weekly but also can supply exceptions (like holidays).

What I need is a complete representation of the available ranges and seats for a given time frame.

So for example a restaurant has a week schedule that says that every weekday they have  `10` seats available, but also has a couple reservations I need the output like this
so I can generate a calendar where the user can see the availability of the restaurant.

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|        start        |         end         | available |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| 2013-02-14 08:00:00 | 2013-02-14 17:00:00 |        10 |
| 2013-02-15 08:00:00 | 2013-02-15 12:00:00 |         8 | <= 2 reservations
| 2013-02-15 12:00:00 | 2013-02-16 15:00:00 |         4 | <= 6 reservations
| 2013-02-15 15:00:00 | 2013-02-16 15:00:00 |         7 | etc...
| 2013-02-16 15:00:00 | 2013-02-16 17:00:00 |         4 |
| 2013-02-17 08:00:00 | 2013-02-17 17:00:00 |        10 |
| 2013-02-18 12:00:00 | 2013-02-18 18:00:00 |        10 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: table got mest up but was supposed to be a 3 column table with start, end, available.

Comment: Does a reservation last all day?  It would seem more logical that the availability is the number of patrons at once, with each reservation lasting for a set estimated minutes-per-size-of-reservation.

Comment: no a reservation lasts only an hour but i need a complete representaion of the available ranges and how many seats there are a available. so lets say that a restaurant has a maximum of 10 seats available on weekdays between 08:00 and 17:00, if there is a reservation on 12:00 till 13:00 for 2 people, the output has to be 

08:00 - 12:00 with 10 available seats,
12:00 - 13:00 with 8 available seats,
13:00 - 17:00 with 10 available seats,

Answer (score 0):

We'll need 2 sets of data: the hours of availability and seats available at a time; and the list of existing reservations.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `availability` (
`dayOpen` date NOT NULL,
`open` time NOT NULL,
`close` time NOT NULL,
`seats` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`dayOpen`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reservations` (
`reservationsid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dayOpen` date NOT NULL,
`start` time NOT NULL,
`seatsUsed` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`reservationsid`)
) ;
```

I'm going to assume that your reservations must start on the hour, and last for 59 minutes. That means our result set will be a list of hours with the number of seats used.  Then pull the days of availability and cycle through to list each hour and how many seats are available.

```
<?php

  $pdoHandle = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);

  // Get all the used seats. Add WHERE with date range to limit results
  $query = 'SELECT dayOpen, start, SUM(seatsUsed) as seatsBooked FROM reservations GROUP BY dayOpen, start';
  $results = $pdoHandle->query($query);
  $allSeatsUsed = array();
  while ( $row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) )
  {  $allSeatsUsed[ $row->dayOpen ][ $row->start ] = $row->seatsBooked;  }

  // GET all possibile seats. Add WHERE with date range to limit results
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM availability ORDER BY dayOpen';
  $results = $pdoHandle->query($query);
  $allSeatsPossible = $results->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  // got through each day to limit results to only open seats
  $finalOpenList = array();
  foreach ( $allSeatsPossible as $dayOpen )
  {
    $finalOpenList[ $dayOpen->dayOpen ] = array();
    $open = new DateTime($dayOpen->open);
    $close = new DateTime($dayOpen-close);
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1H');
    $todaysSlots = new DatePeriod($open,$interval,$close);
    foreach ( $todaysSlots as $slot )
    {
      if ( $allSeatsUsed[ $dayOpen->dayOpen ][ $slot->format('H:i:s') ] < $dayOpen->seats )
      {  $finalOpenList[ $dayOpen->dayOpen ][ $slot->format('H:i:s') ] = 
            $dayOpen->seats - 
            $allSeatsUsed[ $dayOpen->dayOpen ][ $slot->format('H:i:s') ];  }
    }
  }

  // $finalOpenList contains a list of days, with each day 
  // holding a list of hours and the number of slots left per hour
  foreach ( $finalOpenList as $day => $hours )
  {
    $day = new DateTime($day);
    print '<p>'.$day->format('M j, Y').': ';
    if ( sizeof($hours) == 0 )
    {  print 'All seats booked.</p>';  }
    else
    {
      print '</p><ul>';
      foreach ( $hours as $hour=>$seatsLeft )
      {  print '<li>'.$hour.': '.$seatsLeft.' seats available.</li>';  }
      print '</ul>';
    }
  }

?>
```